# what are non synchronized classes? how collections are non sychronized classes?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, backend

Array list and link list both are non synchronized classes what exactly means it? is it mean that multiple threads cannot access the same array list or link list on the same time?

Comment: Too broad: show us a coding example and ask a specific question about it.

Answer (score 1):

This means that if several threads want to access the same linkedlist or arraylist additional synchronization is required to avoid data loss or corruption because of lack of built-in synchronization in those collections.

Comment: TO add more detail-  a synchronized class will make operations like add(), remove(), etc work even if two threads try to do it at the same time-  the resulting list will be consistent with both operations working.  An unsynchronized object will be a bit faster, but if two threads access it the end result could be anything.  There's uses for each.  Also note that this is based on individual operations-  looping over the collection still requires additional synchronization around the loop in most cases, even if the object is synchronized